# Method naming conventions in interfaces ending with -able

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

So let's say I have an `Opener` class or interface (doesn't matter), which has a method `public open(Openable<T> item)`. A `Bag`, `Window`, `Door` implements `Openable` interface, because all of them can be opened.

Question: how should I name method in `Openable` interface? If I name it `void open()` then this will imply that all objects which are `Openable` can open, which is not true, only `Opener` can open `Openable` objects.

Comment: If `Openable` is as simple as having a single `open` method, then why do you need an `Opener`?

Comment: How does the `Opener` interacts with the `Openable` in order to open it? If it only calls an `open` method on the `Openable` then why is the `Opener` necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface is a contract. If a class implements an interface, this means that the class fully supports all operations stated in the interface. (Although this is not ***always*** the case). Regarding the statement in the title: generally all interfaces whose names end with "-able" mark the class as being able to do something. Examples: Runnable - `run()`, Executable - `execute()`, Comparable - `compareTo()`, etc.

A)

```
public interface Openable {
    void open();
}
```

The above interface does indeed imply that any class implementing it can be opened, irrespective of the call context. It does not necessarily mean that the object will open, but that is not the point.

Consider the following, as proposed by @sgj88_:

B)

```
public interface Openable {
    void open(Opener opener);
}
```

Since you state that only `Opener` can open `Openable` objects, theoretically this is a better option. (Ideally, objects should only change their own internals not other objects'). However, in practice `Opener` acts like a behaviour altering object, akin to the strategy pattern.

```
public interface Opener {
    // or something similar
    double fractionToOpen();

    Opener FULL_OPENER = () -> 1.0;
    Opener HALF_OPENER = () -> 0.5;
}
```

The reason for this is that `Opener` does not know anything about the internals of `Openable` in order to change its state, while the name suggests that it does. You wouldn't have `open()` in `Opener` because then you wouldn't need `Opener` in the first place. Hence the semantics of design and implementation do not match.

C)

Since only `Opener` type can open them then it can be assumed that there are more ways to modify the state of `Openable` than just a single call to `open()`.
Then, `Openable` needs more methods for modifying its internal state,e.g.

`setOpenRate(), setOpenFraction()`, etc.

If this is not the case and the question refers to the call privileges, i.e. there is just a single class `Opener` in which `open()` can be used, then it shouldn't be an interface.

Perhaps given some context in which the interface is being designed would help to identify the best option.

Comment: So, in programming, interface such as `Openable` means that the class implementing it, is able to open something, as I understood, while in English it means that the object can be opened. So wouldn't be better to change interface name `Openable` to `Opener`, for less confusion. And those objects who invoke `open` don't need to have any explicit interface saying that it can open something, just arguments to `open` method.

Comment: No, your first thoughts were correct. Example, Window implements Openable means I can then call window.open() to open the window, that is it. The call to open() modifies some internal state of the window which is fine because open() is implemented by the window. In your original case, class Opener implies that it can modify the internal state of window, whereas in reality it can't, so technically class Opener (in this case), as many pointed out, shouldn't exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

I would name it `void openWithOpener()`.
That way you're not tied to one `Opener` and you avoid implying that `Openable` objects can open themselves.

Comment: I don't think is good because a method should not know who will call him. But now it signature says that only `Opener` can call me.

Comment: You have a point there. Since `Openable` objects can _be_ open but they can't _do_ the opening, shouldn't `Openable#open()` deal with the 'open' status of the `Openable` object? In other words, maybe the method should be `boolean isOpen()` and deal with the noun form of 'open' while leaving the verb 'open' to `Opener`.